# Setting screen.fill as a gradient in pygame?

Tags: python, background, pygame, gradient, background-color

I'm trying to set my background as a gradient from black to red (where the transition is vertical/the top is black and the bottom is red). How can I achieve this effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a nice module called [gradients.py](https://www.pygame.org/project/307) by DR0ID.

Here's the simpler vertical gradient function which uses [linear interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation):

```
def vertical(size, startcolor, endcolor):
    """
    Draws a vertical linear gradient filling the entire surface. Returns a
    surface filled with the gradient (numeric is only 2-3 times faster).
    """
    height = size[1]
    bigSurf = pygame.Surface((1,height)).convert_alpha()
    dd = 1.0/height
    sr, sg, sb, sa = startcolor
    er, eg, eb, ea = endcolor
    rm = (er-sr)*dd
    gm = (eg-sg)*dd
    bm = (eb-sb)*dd
    am = (ea-sa)*dd
    for y in range(height):
        bigSurf.set_at((0,y),
                        (int(sr + rm*y),
                         int(sg + gm*y),
                         int(sb + bm*y),
                         int(sa + am*y))
                      )
    return pygame.transform.scale(bigSurf, size)
```

There's also a more versatile `vertical_func` function which allows you to pass different functions for each color channel.

Comment: If anyone wants to learn more about shaping functions with which you can control the gradients, check out [The Book of Shaders](https://thebookofshaders.com/05/).